# mixed model for paired data - 4 level outcome / 3 times

Tags: r

What is the correct test to evaluate the difference between 3 RX readers of the same 50 patients? The rx outcome is a categorical value with 4 ordered levels. The 3 reader have read the RX at the same time.
May I use a mixed model for paired data with patients as random effect?
I'm really in difficulty...

I've tried the repolr package for repeated ordinal scores:

```
repolr(formula = rsna ~ factor(reader)  , 
                    subjects = "Patient" , data = mydata , 
                    categories = 4, times=c(1,2,3), po.test=TRUE,fixed=FALSE)
```

but I obtain this error:

```
Error in ord.expand(space = space, formula = formula, times = times, poly = poly,  : 
  data: model frame and formula mismatch in model.matrix()
```

Here are the data:

```
mydata<- data.frame(Patient = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50),
reader = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3),
rsna  = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 2, 2, 1, 1))
```

`rsna` is my outcome with 4 levels, `Patients` are the 50 patients, `reader` are the 3 readers.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

If you turn the `reader` variable into a factor in the dataset first, it works:

```r
mydata<- data.frame(Patient = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50),
                    reader = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3),
                    rsna  = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 2, 2, 1, 1))


mydata$reader <- as.factor(mydata$reader)
library(repolr)
repolr(formula = rsna ~ reader, 
       subjects = "Patient" , data = mydata , 
       categories = 4, times=c(1,2,3), po.test=TRUE,fixed=FALSE)
#> 
#> repolr: 2016-02-26 version 3.4 
#> 
#> Call:
#> repolr(formula = rsna ~ reader, subjects = "Patient", data = mydata, 
#>     times = c(1, 2, 3), categories = 4, po.test = TRUE, fixed = FALSE)
#> 
#> Coefficients: 
#> cuts1|2  cuts2|3  cuts3|4  reader2  reader3  
#>  1.1761   2.1395   2.9071   0.6600  -0.4768
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Hi! Thank you! I've tried and it doesn't work..I obtain this error message ```Error in smat(coeff = mod.glm$coefficients[1:categories1]) : 
  function 'Rcpp_precious_remove' not provided by package 'Rcpp'```. I've tried both ```install.packages('Rcpp')
library(Rcpp)``` and ```update.packages("Rcpp") ```. It doesn't work.. the application stops with the red RUN button